# Why isn't this code showing the result that I want?

Tags: javascript

```js
let numArr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
numArr2.splice(1, 1);
console.log(`Length of the numArr2 is ${numArr2.length()}`);
```

Why isn't this code showing me the length of `numArr2`?

Comment: `Array.length` is not a method.

Comment: use `numArr2.length`, not `numArr2.length()`

Comment: Read what it's telling you, e.g. `TypeError: [].length is not a function`.

Comment: thanks a lot guys, that was my first question here.

Answer (score 2):

length is a properly and not a method, remove the parenthesis.

```js
let numArr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
numArr2.splice(1, 1);
console.log(`Length of the numArr2 is ${numArr2.length}`);
```